# Protect a single wordpress page and authenticate against an API of external system

Tags: wordpress

I've had a request to provide some internal assistance with our company WordPress website. Its a public site and our marketing team would like to host a single page on there that only existing customers can gain access to. We have an internal in-house developed CRM which the devs have exposed an API to check if an email address provided is that of a customer or not and return a true/false result. The internal CRM uses identity for its auth.

I've done quite a bit of research into the possible options, but none really give a definitive path to achieve this, or offer an alternative solution.

I have a small amount of WP experience, and unfortunately am the only person internally who comes close to being able to "help", however I need some assistance please! What would be the best way to go about securing a single page on a WP site, authenticated by a user providing their email address and it checking the CRM endpoint for true/false validity?

Comment: "Authenticated by a user providing their email address" sounds so wrong. Authentication must at least involve a password, or 2FA mechanism. If each customer owns a WP account for your website, the page in question could be limited to access for logged-in WordPress users. Otherwise, I see no way for managing user credentials.

Comment: It feels wrong too ;). I think the general idea is that its a soft wall on the public website to stop non-customers from accessing customer materials such as help files etc. Its not critical to password protect it, but they want to make it annoying enough so that competitors can't access the page.

Comment: Horrible situation averted after demonstrating how bad this idea really was